# Isolating a particular button for a download() function call in a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am making a tool that has some fields that I type info to.  I have two buttons in my form, one simply clears the fields, and the second I want to initiate a download of the data in the fields. The button code is

```
            <button id="button-reset">Clear</button>
            <button id="button-save">download</button>
```

Where the button attributes are defined in an earlier style definition for a .form_box button{}.   Being very new to javascript I copied the following code to facilitate the download functionality

```js
<script language="Javascript" >
  function download(filename, text) {
  var pom = document.createElement('a');
   pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
   pom.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(pom);
        pom.click();
        document.body.removeChild(pom);
 }
</script>
```

In my form tag I call the download function and pass the parameters I need to name the .txt file to be downloaded as well as the text to put in the file. This is working fine however, the download function is called when **any** button in the form is pressed.  I need to isolate the function call to the "download" button. My thinking is that I need to wrap the pom.click() statement in an if whereby the "if is true" is when the download button is pressed. But I may be completely wrong on that. 
    One of the things I have tried is to remove the download() call from the form tag and place it into the button tag like this:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="download(this['ticket'].value, this['followup'].value); return false" id ="button-save">download</button>
```

This does prevent the "clear" button from making the download() function call, however the "download" button does nothing now.
    Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` was a reference to the form but now it is a reference to the button.
Specifying the form instead of `this` would be fine. For example:

```
<button type="button" onclick="download(document.forms[String form_name]['ticket'].value, document.forms[String form_name]['followup'].value); return false" id ="button-save">download</button>
```

Comment: Perfect!   Thank you very much. My tool is working exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

First language="Javascript" is wrong the standart is type="text/javascript".
And this is how you can modify your form to make your Download function work.

```
<form id="form_id">
   <input name="ticket" type="text">
   <input name="followup" type="text">
   <button id="button-reset" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('form_id').reset();" >clear</button>
   <button id="button-save"  type="button" onclick="download(document.getElementById('form_id')['ticket'].value, document.getElementById('form_id')['followup'].value);" >Download</button>
</form>
```

This Button don't trigger your form because of the `type="button"`.